# How to preg_replace all digits except specific numbers?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

It is necessary to clean a string from everything but English letters, spaces and specific numbers (eg 18,19,20 should be kept in the string).

Please help me with regex `/([^a-zA-Z\s])/` to keep the specified numbers.

Comment: This question seems very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the numbers that you want to keep between word boundaries for example and then make use of SKIP FAIL:

```
\b(?:1[89]|20)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-zA-Z\s]+
```

[Rgex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7LCO10/1)

```
$pattern = "/\b(?:1[89]|20)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[^a-zA-Z\s]+/";
$s="test 18 119 19 50 20 #@$@#%";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $s);
```

Output

```
test 18  19  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE option with `preg_split`:

```
$s="test 18 119 19 50 20 #@$@#%";

echo implode('', preg_split('~\b(1[89]|20)\b|[^a-z\s]+~', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```